# How do I uncheck a box below the one unchecked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have some products listed with checkboxes.  Some products get free gifts which get listed under the product as a separate product.  When you check a box I need the product undernealth to be checked aswell and also to do the reverse so when the first product is unticked the one under gets unticked. I have the first bit working but can not reverse the process.

```
<script>   
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// wrap this code in a "DOM ready" handler
$j(function() {
// listen to change event instead (to support keyboard driven interaction)
$j('input:checkbox').change(function() {   
    if (this.checked) {

        var original = +$j(this).attr("id");
        var temp = original + 1;

        var follower = $j("#" + temp);         

if (original  %2 != 0){
        follower.attr("checked","checked");
}
else
{
  original.removeAttr("checked");   
}                           
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery .next() to get the next check box rather then query the dom for the id

try this link for the docs [Jquery next.()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the next checkbox like this:

```
var temp = original.nextAll("input[type=checkbox]:first");
```